# Create a AD-LDS partition under a child of the primary partition

Tags: windows-server-2008, partition, ad-lds

I have a AD-LDS instance running on a Server 2008 R2. I have this application partition, created at installation :

```
dc=enterprise,dc=example,dc=com
```

I have succesfully followed this [procedure to create application partitions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc816739%28v=ws.10%29.aspx). They are named :

```
cn=stuff,dc=enterprise,dc=example,dc=com
cn=things,dc=enterprise,dc=example,dc=com
```

If I configure my client(s) to follow referals, I can search from `dc=enterprise,dc=example,dc=com` and find objects under `cn=stuff` and `cn=things`.

How can I create (or move after the fact) the `stuff` and `things` partitions so they are logically located under a OU under the initial partition, ending up with something like :

```
cn=stuff,ou=applications,dc=enterprise,dc=example,dc=com
cn=things,ou=applications,dc=enterprise,dc=example,dc=com
```